# Messaging system mysql, list of messages

Tags: mysql, max

I am making a messaging system, similiar to facebooks.

I have two tables:

```
messages =>
  m_id (message id)
  t_id (thread id)
  author_id (id of user that wrote the message)
  text (Text for the message)
  date (date)
  time (time)

thread_recipients =>
  t_id (thread_id)
  user_id (id of the user that will belong to this thread)
  read (Flag to tell if there are any unread messages)
```

So what i basically want is to get a list of the threads (conversations) that a user is part of. In that list i want to select the text, date and time of the last message that was posted in the thread.

I have made a sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3d9b/2

So basically i want this query to only return the last row, since it has the highest message id.

If it could be done without a subquery, that would be great. If not, then i'll just have to live with that (:

**EDIT:**
I figured out how to do it with a subquery. But my big concern here is performance. I would very much like to do it another way if possible.

```
SELECT r.t_id, m.author_id, left(m.text, 50)
FROM
messages m,
thread_recipients r
WHERE
r.user_id = 16 and
r.t_id = m.t_id and
m.m_id = (SELECT MAX(mm.m_id) FROM messages mm WHERE mm.t_id = m.t_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php
I think this is what you need.

Comment: Well i do know about max, but my problem is how to implement it, preferably without a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT r.t_id, m.author_id, left(m.text, 50)
FROM messages m, thread_recipients r
WHERE
r.user_id = 16 and r.t_id = m.t_id
GROUP BY m.m_id
ORDER BY m.m_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I've updated your [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3d9b/39)

Comment: Just tried this and added user 16 to thread 2 and removed the limit. That returned all 6 messages. I need to select all the threads the user is in, but only get the text from the latest one. But i like this method though, can it work?